# DataTable - Abrir modal desde un icono

Tags: javascript, datatables

Buen día,

Estoy usando datatables, así como también abp framework, en este caso cambie los botones de editar y eliminar por iconos, por lo que la acción de dar clic botón abría un modal con la información a editar.

Con este cambio y agregando tal icono, la acción de abrir el modal ya no funciona, esta es la variable del modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#ClientesTable').DataTable();

    table.on('click', 'tr .editButton', function (data) {
        editModal.open({ id: data.id });
    });
});
```

Y aquí es donde esta el datable:

```
var dataTable = $('#ClientesTable').DataTable(
    abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
        serverSide: true,
        paging: true,
        order: [[1, "asc"]],
        searching: false,
        scrollX: true,
        ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(rocaport.salesService.services.cliente.getListCliente, inputAction),
        columnDefs:
        [
                {
                    title: l('Actions'),
                    defaultContent: ["<i class='fa fa-pencil editButton'></i>" + '&nbsp; &nbsp' +
                        "<i class='fa fa-trash deleteButton'></i>"],
                    className: 'dt-body-left'
                },
                    }
                },
            {
                title: "Nombre",
                data: "nombre"
            }, 
           ]
         })
       );
```

He visto algunos ejemplos, pero sigue sin funcionarme, por lo que agradecería de sus amables comentarios para poder llegar a la solución.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Y tu html como lo tienes?

Comment: Primeramente, los fragmentos que agregue están en un index.js y en index.cshtml el html de la tabla lo tengo de esta forma:                                          
<abp-card-body>
    <abp-table striped-rows="true" id="ClientesTable"></abp-table>
 </abp-card-body>

Comment: Estas utilizando algún framework?

Comment: Así es, es abp framework.

Comment: Lo que yo hago es poner una clase `edit-button", y luego con jquery tomar ventaja de los [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), para que los botones tomen el evento declarado: `('#ClientesTable').on('click', '.btn-editar', function (data) { editModal.open({id: data.record.id });`